# Change icon color based on the value

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-class

I am a newbie to Angular2 and I want to know how to change the CSS of an icon conditionally based on the values.

In HTML:

```
<li><i class="fa fa-check" [style.color]="'switch(types)'"></i>{{ types }}</li>
```

types contains a lot of integers ranges from 1-3.

In ts:

```
switch(p) {
    if(p==0) {...} //return color red
    if(p==1) {...} //return color blue
    if(p==2) {...} //return color green
}
```

This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Is it in ngfor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Switch** uses **case** in its body which is missing. Other way is to use function binding (which is not preferred) but couldn't find any other solution.

```
[style.color]="color(types)"


color(p) {
    if(p==0) {return 'green'} 
    if(p==1) {return 'red'} 
    if(p==2) {return 'blue'} 
}
```

**DEMO** : https://plnkr.co/edit/zQ79mbS2U3X1s9ktnTIR?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
   <li>
        <i class="fa fa-check" [ngStyle]="{'color': switch(types)}"> 
            {{types}}
        </i>   
   </li>


switch(p) {
    if(p==0) {return 'red'} 
    if(p==1) {return 'blue'} 
    if(p==2) {return 'green'} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered but another potential approach.

For a small bounded set of values you could also just do this inside the [ngClass]. It would look like

```
[ngClass]="{'red':types === 0,
  'blue':types === 1,
  'green':types === 2}"
```

This works because the values are independent. You would also have to declare the new classes in your css file.

```
.red{
   color:red;
    }
.green{
   color:green;
 }
.blue{
   color:blue;
 }
```

This should reduce the overhead of having to call a method every time the run time recalculates the layout. This approach is probably what I would use for your example. For more complex criteria or a larger set of values I would probably go with the function call approach.

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this :

```
<li><i class="fa fa-check" [ngStyle]="changeCSS(types)"></i>{{ types }}</li>


      changeCSS(types:any){
    let style:any;
      if(types == 0){
        style={
          'background':'..',
          'border-color':'....',
          'border-bottom': '...',

        }
    }
return style;
}
```

Hope this helps

EDIt: Have removed the `''` as suggested

Comment: This approach has several flaws. It won't work at all because of the redundant quotes `''` around `changesCSS(types)` and it's quite a bad idea because it returns a new class instance every time `changeCSS()` is called. This basically breaks Angulars change detection. It should at least cache and reuse the created `style` object.

Comment: I forgot to remove the ' ' . copied the whole thing direclty . That aside, [ngStyle] is not the suitable way  ? can i know in what way i can implement this ?

Comment: `ngStyle` is fine (didn't have a too close look at the actual problem stated in the question). The problem is that `changeCSS()` returns a new object every time it is called.

Comment: so i have to declare a global variable & assign the style to that varaible ?

Comment: Doesn't have to be global. Just a field inside the components class, but otherwise, yes, that's the way to go. The problem is that from the question it's not clear what can be used as event to trigger an update of the "global variables" value.

Comment: Oh okay . True about the trigger event ,